# Web applet/jnlp to get System information (current ram/cpu used, current apps running)

Tags: web-apps

Does anyone have example library, tool, or web applet or JNLP code that, if a 'web application is running poorly', to be able to ask the user to run a java applet or JNLP java application (so chrome/firefox/ie browsers), to get the users desktop resource usage information?

- CPU used
- Ram used (if shows swap space, great)
- Ping or tracert results to common locations
- Apps currently running, and if possible their memory footprint (the browser is running slow because you are running excel, outlook, 20 tabs of the browser with youtube videos running in the background...)

3 out of 4 would be great even, just something to help differentiate between web application issues and other resource (desktop, network) so can fix the right problem.

TIA, -D

Comment: A large part of the point of Java is that it runs a VM so doesn't know/care about the hardware/OS while getting the sort of information you are looking for is going to need to be hardware & OS specific so I suspect you are going to be out of luck.